# Flickr API to html gallery by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, flickr

this is my first time on the website to apologies if this is in there wrong forum.

I am trying to pull images from a flickr set for a lightbox gallery on my website. The light gallery needs the photos coding in the following way:

```
<ul>
    <li data-type="media" data-url="FULL SIZE URL"></li>
    <li data-thumbnail-path="THUMBNAIL URL"></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to insert the photos in a div I named `<div id="test"><div>` This is my javascript I made after consulting the Flick API faq and looking at other code:

```
$(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    data: {
        format: 'json',
        method: 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
        api_key: 'MY KEY',
        photoset_id: 'THE SET I'M USING',
        per_page: '50'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
}).done(function (data) {
    var gallery = $('#test'),
        url;
$.each(data.photoset.photo, function (index, photo) {
        url = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' +
            photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret;
        $('<ul>')
            .append($('<li>').prop('data-url', url + '_b.jpg').prop('data-type', 'media'))
            .append($('<li>').prop('data-thumbnail-path', url + '_s.jpg'))
        .appendTo(gallery);
    }); 
});
```

Currently, I put the javascript in my html header but the div is empty when I run the page.

What have I missed?

Thank you!

UPDATE 1: I had missed a `});` at end of the js code. Thanks @dfsq 
Now we have then append part partially working however the flickr data is still not being passed to the li props. Here's a snippet of what in currently being inserted

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE 2: By changing every `.prop` to `.attr` the remaining problem has been resolved....

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: @dfsq Yes! I missed a `});` at the end. However, the problem persists and now there are no errors.

I added `$('<p>Test</p>').appendTo('#test');` above and below my js. Now the div displays one "test" but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected js is as follows:

```
$(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    data: {
        format: 'json',
        method: 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
        api_key: 'MY KEY',
        photoset_id: 'THE SET I'M USING',
        per_page: '50'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
}).done(function (data) {
    var gallery = $('#test'),
        url;
$.each(data.photoset.photo, function (index, photo) {
        url = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' +
            photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret;
        $('<ul>')
            .append($('<li>').attr('data-url', url + '_b.jpg').attr('data-type', 'media'))
            .append($('<li>').attr('data-thumbnail-path', url + '_s.jpg'))
        .appendTo(gallery);
    }); 
  });
});
```